# CakePHP 2.x Custom Route with Arguments

Tags: cakephp, parameters, routes, arguments

In my CakePHP App I'd like to pass arguments in a custom route.

**What works now**

> (domain/controller/action/param)

domain.com/dealers/view/1

**What I'd like to do**

> (domain/param/controller/action/param)

domain.com/washington/dealers/view/1

**This is my code in routes.php:**

```
Router::connect('/:city/dealers/view/:id', array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'view'), 

    array(
        'pass' => array('city', 'id')
        ),

    array('city' => '[a-z]+')
    );
```

This just redirects *domain.com/washington/dealers/view/1* to *domain.com/dealers/index* for the obvious reason that I did not properly pass the parameters. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

city should not be in a separate array ex:

```
Router::connect(
   '/:city/dealers/view/:id', 
   array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'index'),
   array(
    'pass' => array('city', 'id'),
    'city' => '[a-z]+'
));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change it.

Comment: you probably have two routes in conflict, because I checked the example and it works fine! OR your view from the link is bad. Could you write it here?

Comment: also you should add : 'id'=>'[0-9]+' to the array

Comment: I checked route conflicts (deleted the others) and the view, they are fine! I altered the route to: 

`Router::connect('/:city/dealers/view/:id', array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'view', 1));`

This works fine, so I still think theres sth. wrong with passing the id …

Comment: You were right, I made a mistake in my method. I set `$city = null` and now it works fine. Thanks a lot.