# Routing in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I've a similar question to 
[CakePHP 2.x Custom Route with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778771/cakephp-2-x-custom-route-with-arguments) whereby I would like to use the parameter as one of my variable.

(domain/param/controller/action/param)

```
Router::connect(
    '/:sitecode/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array('sitecode' => '[A-Z]{20}', 'persist' => array('sitecode'))
);
```

The above code is not working, it still treat the `:sitecode` as a controller, and `:controller` as an action. What did I do wrong?

How am I able to access the `:sitecode` from my code later?

Answer (score 2):

```
Customize your route like this:

Router::connect(
   '/:sitecode/:controller/:action/*',
   array('controller' => :controller, 'action' => :action),
   array('sitecode' => '[A-Z]{20}', pass => ['sitecode'])
);
Later in your code get sitecode using - $this->request->params['sitecode']
```